# rails form_with check_box is not rendering value of object on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following form allows the changing of an attribute vie UJS, the returning block of HTML is rendered correctly

```
<% @product.productviews.each do |productview| %>
  <%= form_with(url: update_productview_products_path(productview_id: productview.id), method: :patch) do |form| %>
    <%= productview.active %> <%= form.check_box :active %> 
    <%= form.submit t('update') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Class `Product` is a parent of `has_many   :productviews`.  context: rails 6.1.3

However when refreshing the page the check_box is invariably set to false, notwithstanding the value of the attribute:

```
<form action="/products/update_productview?productview_id=1" [...]
  true <input name="active" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="active" id="active" />  

<form action="/products/update_productview?productview_id=2" [...]
  true <input name="active" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="active" id="active" />  

<form action="/products/update_productview?productview_id=3" [...]
  true <input name="active" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="active" id="active" />  

<form action="/products/update_productview?productview_id=4" [...]
  false <input name="active" type="hidden" value="0" /><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="active" id="active" />
```

Which is unexpected.  [Rails guides specify](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/form_helpers.html#combining-them) that Array parameters do not play well with the check_box helper. This instance is not a case of array parameters, although it is an array of forms.

However switching to `<%= form.check_box_tag "active" %>` or `<%= form.check_box_tag :active %>` will return

```
undefined method `check_box_tag' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:
```

which again seems contrary to what the [Rails guides purport](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-tag-helpers-without-a-form-builder)

Can check_box be used in an array of forms? How can this checkbox show the value of the attribute on page load?

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the model to the form

```rb
<%= form_with(url: update_productview_products_path(productview_id: productview.id), method: :patch, model: productview) do |form| %>
```

if this does not work you can pass a `checked` into the `check_box` input but I advise to use the first option if its working

```
<%= form.check_box :active, checked: productview.active %>
```